# How to write GetEnumerator() for a Binary Search Tree?

Tags: c#, algorithm, generics, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I have a `BinaryTree` class and a `BinaryTreeNode` for holding nodes, I have already made the tree and write the pre-order, postorder and **in-order** method for it.
but i don't know how to write `IEnumerator<T>` for it (I only want to use **in-order** for `GetEnumerator()` method).
The problem is that return type of `inOrder` method is `void`. I want to make it `IEnumerator<T>` and instead of `MessageBox` return data.

How can I do that?

```
public void PreOrder(BinaryTreeNode<T> node)
{
    if (node != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(node.Value.ToString());
        PreOrder(node.Left);
        PreOrder(node.Right);
    }
}

public void PostOrder(BinaryTreeNode<T> node)
{
    if (node != null)
    {
        PostOrder(node.Left);
        PostOrder(node.Right);
        MessageBox.Show(node.Value.ToString());
    }
}

public void InOrder(BinaryTreeNode<T> node)
{
    if (node != null)
    {
        InOrder(node.Left);
        MessageBox.Show(node.Value.ToString());
        InOrder(node.Right);
    }
}

public void Clear()
{
    root = null;
    Count = 0;
}

public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    InOrder(root);
    return null; // error in forerach loop
}

IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return GetEnumerator();
}
```

I think this part of my code is enough.
This is how I defined the `BinaryTree` class:

```
public class BinaryTree<T> : IEnumerable<T> where T : IComparable<T>
```

and this is how I defined `BinaryTreeNode`:

```
public class BinaryTreeNode<T> : IComparable<T> where T : IComparable<T>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one way to do it, using `yield`:

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    if (Left != null)
    {
        foreach(var v in Left)
        {
            yield return v;
        }
    }

    yield return Value;

    if (Right != null) 
    {
        foreach (var v in Right)
        {
            yield return v;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is a more concise approach using Linq:

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    var leftEnumerable = (IEnumerable<T>)Left ?? new T[0];
    var rightEnumerable = (IEnumerable<T>)Right ?? new T[0];

    return leftEnumerable.Concat(new T[] { Value })
                         .Concat(rightEnumerable)
                         .GetEnumerator();
}
```

**Edit:** Since you seem to have separate classes for `BinaryTree` and `BinaryTreeNode`, you can put either of the above in `BinaryTreeNode`, and put the following in `BinaryTree`:

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    return Root.GetEnumerator();
}
```

Comment: I don't have a Left property in BinaryTree. it is in BinaryTreeNode. and GetEnumerator() is in BinaryTree. So Left,  and Right doesn't work here. Do you want To see the full Code?